# AngularJS Ionic: Unable to inject Ionic History

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to inject ionic history in my Ionic Project and I am getting this error

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24ionicHistoryProvider%20%3C-%20%24ionicHistory
```

This is my complete controller code

```
.controller('menu', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicHistory', function($scope,$state,$ionicHistory) {  //first menu
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    $scope.gotoUser = function(){

        localStorage.removeItem("selectedName");
         localStorage.setItem("selectedName",username);
        $state.go("Page");
    };

    $scope.gotoLogouts = function() {
       // localStorage.clear();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        //localStorage.removeItem('user');
        $state.go("login");

}])
```

Please what am doing wrong.

Comment: post your module declaration.

Comment: module declaration means 'angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])' like this.

Comment: angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','ngResource'])

Comment: can you share your overall error log: your code above seems alright...and the log doesn't suffice much to help.

Comment: you forgotted '};' in gotoLogouts function. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Cordova?
If you are, it is probably happening because you did not inject ngCordova in your module.

Like: 
angular.module('anotei', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

Answer (score 0):

my friend your problem is not in you `$ionicHistory`, it is in the locatStorage. you are not injecting the local storage in the controller. Just inject it and it will work.

Cheers.

Comment: I dont think locaStorage needs injecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the closing curly bracket } for the $scope.gotoLogouts function, just before the last line.

Answer (score 0):

@Nadeem Khoury you should not inject localStorage. It is $localStorage that should be injected but he is using localStorage which should not be injected.

If this is exactly the code you are using, I am with @Ennedigi

```
.controller('menu', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicHistory', function($scope,$state,$ionicHistory) {  //first menu
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    $scope.gotoUser = function(){

        localStorage.removeItem("selectedName");
         localStorage.setItem("selectedName",username);
        $state.go("Page");
    };

    $scope.gotoLogouts = function() {
       // localStorage.clear();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        //localStorage.removeItem('user');
        $state.go("login");
}

}])
```

Comment: curly backet is added before last line

Answer (score 0):

try to include timeout, location and windows in module

```
    IonicModule
.factory('$ionicHistory', [
  '$rootScope',
  '$state',
  '$location',
  '$window',
  '$timeout',
  '$ionicViewSwitcher',
  '$ionicNavViewDelegate',
function($rootScope, $state, $location, $window, $timeout, $ionicViewSwitcher, $ionicNavViewDelegate) {
```

Answer (score 0):

@Blaze, you have to inject $localStorage in your controller like below,

```
.controller('menu', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicHistory', '$localStorage' function($scope,$state,$ionicHistory,$localStorage) {  //first menu
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    $scope.gotoUser = function(){

        localStorage.removeItem("selectedName");
         localStorage.setItem("selectedName",username);
        $state.go("Page");
    };

    $scope.gotoLogouts = function() {
       // localStorage.clear();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        //localStorage.removeItem('user');
        $state.go("login");
}

}])
```